# calling `numpy.where` on a `masked_array`

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, masked-array

Here's an example:

```
import numpy
from numpy import arange, where
from numpy.ma import masked_array

a = masked_array(arange(10), arange(10) < 5)
print(where((a <= 6))[0])
```

Expected output:

```
[5, 6]
```

Actual output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How can I achieve the expected output?  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to use "numpy.ma.where" in order to handle the masked array:

```
print(numpy.ma.where((a <= 6))[0])
```

Comment: Oh okay--Thanks!  Before I read the docs, I was thinking maybe `masked_where` was the answer.  I searched "where" on what I thought was the `numpy.ma` docs page and didn't see anything other than `masked_where`.